# Substitute a variable value in another variable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a scrolling plugin which after initialization stores the scroll amount in the specific id.

I am using jQuery to get the id of the div and storing it in variable bid.

```
var bid = $(this).parent().parent().find(".video_s").attr('id');
```

In console var bid returns the element ID. (This Works correctly)

As the scroll amount is stored in objects specific to DOM element IDs

```
var bpos = bid.scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0];
```

**THE ABOVE CODE IS NOT WORKING**

variable bid contains the id of the element.

If i type `elementID.scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0]` in console, it perfectly returns the scroll amount. where elementID is the specific ID if the horizontal container.

Please can anybody tell me whats wrong?

**SOLUTION 1:**
`window[bid].scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0]`

**SOLUTION 2:**
`eval(bid).scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0]`

**NOTE: never use `eval()`. `eval()` is slow and a security risk**

Comment: `bid` is a string, how should it has `scrollData` property?

Comment: ok! xdazz can you please tell me, how should i pass the element id to get the scroll amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `bid` is only the string containing the element-id but you need a jQuery Object containing the actual dom-element, the code should be:

```
var bpos = $('#'+bid).scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0];
```

`$('#'+bid)` gets the element according to ID stored in bid.

In the case of this plugin the elements are stored in a global variable (which is btw. very bad programming style), so you can use the following to access them:

```
window[bid].scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0];
```

Comment: @KakiR What's the name of that plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store the position and not the id

```
var bid = $(this).parent().parent().find(".video_s").attr('id');
var bpos = $('#'+bid).scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0]
```

Comment: I am getting the elem ID using jQuery, and how to access the scroll value relative to that ID?

Comment: Can your try $('#'+bid).get().scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0] and eval(bid).scrollData.scrollPosition[0][0] see if any of these 2 give you what you want

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: @KakiR never use eval! It's slow and a security risk. Also it's not working in Ecmasript5. use `window[bid]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$('#'+bid).scrollData.scrollposition[0][0];
```